# Solutions For Nonce Error Caused By Threaded API Calls?

Tags: python, multithreading, nonce

I'm making API Calls on Threads.  The API requires each call to have Nonce greater then the last call.

I'm generating Nonce using this code:

req['nonce'] = int(time.time()*1000000)

I'm getting errors:

"{u'error': u'Nonce must be greater than 1427495062551856. You provided 1427495062544266.'}".

I believe the cause of the error is slight variations in API request/response times is causing one API request to reach the server ahead of a prior request (that would have a lower Nonce).

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem when using Poloniex crypto currency exchange API. Some buy or sell calls were hanging for 2 minutes for some reason (you probably could ask Poloniex why it's like that). My calls were asynchronous, so new calls were made without waiting for "hung" calls.

I just re-made these hung calls checking for a "Nonce must be greater than " prefix on error string. You can see the code in my [github repo](https://github.com/loziniak/cinx/commit/ea3a07f6abe3217c9daf0c0321729ddda6bd9fe7)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer will depend heavily on how costly a rejection from the foreign API is.

Avoiding *all* errors from your multiple independent clients might be impossible.  Your threads would have to co-ordinate between themselves when creating each nonce, so that they are created in increasing order.  Also when using each nonce, so they don't arrive at the far end out of order.  And finally, each thread has to inform the others when the nonce it *was* using has been seen by the remote API, since saying "I'm now sending nonce 1000" lays claim to 1000 *and all greater values* until that thread is done with 1000, at which point it is safe for some other thread to try 1001.

If the cost of a bad API call is really bad, you might have a situation in which only one thread can use that API at a time --- each thread would have to claim some exclusive lock, handle the nonce and API call, and then release the lock.  This might defeat your purpose for using threads.

I think the better solution is to have each thread handle these rejections by creating a new nonce and retrying the API call.  You'll probably need such a function anyway, since even if you created the nonce values perfectly, variations in network speed and routing could cause those requests to reach the API server out of order.

In short, I don't think you can eliminate these errors, so focus on reducing their cost.